# Not getting a new line when using fprintf

Tags: matlab, console, printf, newline, error-logging

I wrote a small function for the pyhtagorean value:

```
function c = pyth(a,b)
% Takes two inputs of same size and returns the pythagorean of the 2 inputs
if size(a) == size(b) % checks for same size
    c = sqrt(a.*a + b.*b);  % calculates the pythagorean value
else
    fprintf('Error: Input sizes are not equal'); % returns if sizes are not the same
end
```

It works correctly, but after it returns, the '>>' is on the same line as my output, rather than a fresh line beneath the output. This is only the case for the `fprintf`.  Here:

```
>> pyth([1 2;3 4],[5 6;7 8])
ans =
    5.0990    6.3246
    7.6158    8.9443
>>
```

```
>> pyth([1 2],[1 2;3 4])
Error: Input sizes are not equal>>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fprintf` is typically for writing to files (hence the `f` in the beginning). When writing to (text) files, the way to ensure OS-independent line breaks is to add `\r\n` (aka CRLF, or `[char(10) char(13)]`) at the end of your string. It appears that when printing to the console, this is not important (i.e. `\n` also works in MATLAB running on Linux).

Several tips:

- You can use [`disp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html) or [`display`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/display.html) instead, as they add the newline character for you.
- If you want to display an error, why not use [`error`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html)?
- If you use `fprintf` for printing errors, you might want to start by `fprintf(2, ... )` as this will print the text to stderr, making it error-colored (typically red).

Answer (score 3):

Use \n for a newline:

```
fprintf('Error: Input sizes are not equal\n');
```

Comment: (Edit: in response to the comment, now deleted, that "newline" would be better) Well, it is the same as \n , so whichever you prefer is fine. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/newline.html